# How is this wrong?[HackerRank Loop in java]

Tags: java

I am doing this problem in HackerRank https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-loops-i/copy-from/26053352

My code outputs the same exact answer as the expected output as the expected answer. But my answer is wrong and only passes the first test case. Wtf am I doing wrong?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = 2;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%d x %d = %d\n", n, i, i*n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read the value of n from the user, not give it in the program.

Comment: @T-Dot1992 - Please accept one of the answer, if they have helped. If not, please clarify below the answerer's post the issue. See how to accept an answer -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at the website, they seem to provide you with a template where N is given as program input.

I didn't sign up to verify, but perhaps you could paste this code in and see if it gets marked correctly?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = in.nextInt();
        for (int i=1; i <= 10; i++)
            System.out.println(N + " x " + i + " = " + N*i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accept input from user, and append a new line after every print statement.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d x %d = %d\n", n, i, i*n);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`N` must be user input for passing other remaining tests because you have not making N as general .
Do this

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
int N=scan.nextInt();
```